# In iOS 10, how can I make notifications appear center screen?

Tags: notifications, reminders

I use Reminders a lot, and every time I get one it appears at the top of my screen. The trouble is if I haven't used my phone for a few hours, there are sometimes many notifications all queued up that begin to appear one after another as soon as I use my phone again.  But in that moment I am trying to quickly access something on my phone, and the annoying reminder at the top of the screen gets in the way of me trying to tap on something towards the top. This inevitably results in me launching the Reminders or Calendar apps instead of the thing I was trying to tap on.

Is there any way to make reminders appear in the center of the screen, instead of at the top? This has driven me crazy for years and I've never been able to find a solution.

Comment: Do you mean you want it to appear in the "Alert"-style notification rather than a banner, or that you want the banner to be in the middle of the screen?

Comment: I mean center of the screen. As far as I can tell all available styles still appear at the top of the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all available styles"--there are three options for notification type: Banner (it appears as a bar at the top of the screen for a few seconds), Alert (it pops up a dialog box in the middle of the screen which stays there until you interact with it), and None (nothing displays on the screen at all; notifications are only visible in Notification Center and the lock screen, if you have those enabled for the app in question).

Comment: Given that information, is one of those what you want?

Comment: Alerts style does not appear in the center of the screen. I am already using that style and it always appears at the top of the screen.

Comment: By the way I am not referring to the notification Center.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry; apparently I haven't used alerts since before iOS 10. You're completely correct.

Comment: Darn, you had my hopes up there for a moment… Fingers crossed that someone has some idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: I would be shocked if this was possible without a jailbreak. Sorry.